# `math.floor(1 - (1 / (float("inf"))))` doesn't return 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I would expect

```py
math.floor(1 - (1 / (float("inf"))))
```

to return 0, since any `1 - e` where e is an arbitrarily small number will always be smaller than 1, which means math.floor should return 0. Instead it returns 1.

This doesn't happen because `math.floor(1 / float("inf")` evaluates to 0. What's a better way to achieve this desired outcome?

---

Further context:
I currently have the variables `a` and `b` which are floats between 0 and 1 (noninclusive), I want to know by how much to modify `b` such that it will change the boolean outcome of a comparison like:

```
a < b
```

E.g. if `a > b == True` then `b += (a - b)` would cause `a > b` to evaluate as `False` (success!). However, it does not work with `a < b` because after `b += (a - b)` it will be the case that `a == b` not that `a < b`. To make `a` less than `b` an additional small value `e` needs to be added to `b` as well.

Another way to ask this question is, "How do I get that small value `e` (epsilon) to add to `b` such that it will always change the value of `a < b` after applying `b += (a - b) + e`?"

Comment: What **does** it return?

Comment: Have you evaluated `1 / (float("inf"))`? `what's a better way to achieve this desired outcome` -- what exactly is your desired outcome?

Comment: "Arbitrarily small number" would refer to 1/x where x is any large and FINITE number you can think of. But once you throw the actual term infinity into the mix, things get complicated. While 1/(1000000000000) would be a really small number, 1/infinity will always return 0. So 1-(1/float("inf")) returns just 1, not 0.99999999...

Comment: @AndrewHenle returns 1

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yeah it returns 0.0, I'm asking what I should evaluate instead of `float("inf")` to achieve my desired result

Comment: If your desired outcome is `zero`, I've found `0.0` works pretty well.

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to `math.floor(1 - 0.0)` so 1 is exactly what you should expect

Comment: @MarkMeyer hilarious. What I'm trying to do is modify a float [0, 1) such that it's just a bit bigger than another float. `b += (a - b)` doesn't work because then `b == a` I need `b > a == True`  after applying the delta. In other words, I need a minimum epsilon to add to the equation `b += (a - b) + e` such that `b > a`. How do I get that minimum epsilon?

Comment: @Connor Why do you want to do that with an epsilon rather than just asking for the next larger float?

Comment: @KellyBundy Great, how to ask for the next larger float?

Comment: @Connor https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nextafter

Comment: @KellyBundy great, I'll edit my question for clarity and if you write an answer with this I'll accept it. Thank you for your help

Comment: Connor, I wonder if `math.floor(1 - sys.float_info.epsilon)` would work for you?

Comment: I'll be away, feel free to use it in an answer yourself if that works for you.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Amazing, I did not know that existed. Which is a better approach, `sys.float_info.epsilon` or `math.nextafter` (assuming both packages are already imported)

Comment: @Connor I'm not sure about `nextafter`.  It looks great, but it's new and I'm not up to 3.9 anywhere yet.

Comment: The difference is that `math.nextafter` guarantees giving you a larger result (except in the case of infinity) whereas adding epsilon doesn't guarantee giving you a different result (e.g. `1e10 + epsilon == 1e10`).

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you! And thank you all for your help. I've edited the question to make it clearer and if none of you want to write an answer I'll come back and write one myself using your comments.

Please let me know if I can do anything else to improve this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.nextafter

and

`sys.float_info.epsilon`

Should help

Answer (score 0):

You will be getting `1.0` as the answer, not `0`. This is because `1/inf` will be taken as `0` and not something which is a small number. So `1-0` will result in a number with no floating points, and that's why even when you use `floor` or `ceil` you will get `1.0` in this case but if you want to achieve the return value of `0` you can use any other number instead of `inf`.
It will solve your problem.